# Move into lambda expression in c++11

Tags: c++11, lambda, move

I'm trying to work around the c++11 lambda-capture restriction with moving in question.

The following code runs with visual studio 2013, but not with g++ (invalid field error). What is wrong with the code? How can i fix it.

```
template <typename T>
struct move_on_copy
{
    using T_t = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;
    mutable T_t _val;

    move_on_copy(){}

    move_on_copy(T_t&& v):_val(std::move(v)){}
    move_on_copy(move_on_copy const& v):_val(std::move(v._val)){}
    move_on_copy& operator=(move_on_copy const& v)
    { _val =std::move(v._val); return *this; }
};

//...
auto tt = move_on_copy<Packaged_Task<R2()>>(std::move(task));
auto work = [tt](){tt._val();}; //compiler error here
```

**Full Error Message:**

```
/home/christofmatthaei/Desktop/untitled folder/trunk/Concurrency/inc/Concurrency/ThreadPool/Future.h: In instantiation of ‘struct it::crc::Future<R>::then(F) [with F = it::crc::when_all(InputIterator, InputIterator) [with InputIterator = std::_List_iterator<it::crc::Future<int> >; decltype (begin->.get()) = int]::<lambda(it::crc::Future<int>&&)>; R = int; typename it::crc::callable_traits<F>::return_type = std::vector<it::crc::Future<int>, std::allocator<it::crc::Future<int> > >]::<lambda()>’:
/home/christofmatthaei/Desktop/untitled folder/trunk/Concurrency/inc/Concurrency/ThreadPool/Future.h:303:33:   required from ‘it::crc::Future<typename it::crc::callable_traits<F>::return_type> it::crc::Future<R>::then(F) [with F = it::crc::when_all(InputIterator, InputIterator) [with InputIterator = std::_List_iterator<it::crc::Future<int> >; decltype (begin->.get()) = int]::<lambda(it::crc::Future<int>&&)>; R = int; typename it::crc::callable_traits<F>::return_type = std::vector<it::crc::Future<int>, std::allocator<it::crc::Future<int> > >]’
/home/christofmatthaei/Desktop/untitled folder/trunk/Concurrency/inc/Concurrency/ThreadPool/When.h:29:21:   required from ‘it::crc::Future<std::vector<it::crc::Future<decltype (begin->.get())> > > it::crc::when_all(InputIterator, InputIterator) [with InputIterator = std::_List_iterator<it::crc::Future<int> >; decltype (begin->.get()) = int]’
/home/christofmatthaei/Desktop/untitled folder/trunk/Concurrency/test/Future.cpp:253:62:   required from here
/home/christofmatthaei/Desktop/untitled folder/trunk/Concurrency/inc/Concurrency/ThreadPool/Future.h:303:17: **error: using invalid field** ‘it::crc::Future<R>::then(F)::<lambda()>::<tt capture>’
    auto work = [tt](){tt._val();};
```

**Edit:**
I use g++ on version 5.3.1

Comment: which version of g++ not work? I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: Don't do this.  You create an object that lies about being copied.  You then proceed to infect the lambda you generate: that lambda *also* lies about being copied.  Put that in a `std::function`?  It will lie too!  Pass it to a `std::` algorithm?  Who knows what will happen!  This is the same thing that `std::auto_ptr` did, and `auto_ptr` is so horrilbe it was actually removed from the standard despite the bias against breaking existing code: all code with `auto_ptr` was presumed broken.